# Notification Icon context menu

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying click on a menu item in a context menu that is activated by right clicking the taskbar notification icon for the application. I am stumped on how to access the menu. The following code activated the menu but I am not sure how to proceed from there. I am unable to get any information for the popup context menu. Swapy doesn't show any info for the menu.

```
def anchor_main_window(self, tip="Tooltip Text"):
    self.trace("anchor main window")
    taskbar.RightClickHiddenSystemTrayIcon(tip)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWAPY supports "win32" backend only while pywinauto 0.6.0+ also supports "uia" backend (MS UI Automation technology). Differences are described in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) - highly recommended to read.

If your app is WPF, you must do something like that:

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="your_app.exe")
print(app.ContextMenu.menu_items(), )
app.ContextMenu.ApproxMenuItemName.invoke()
```

So the taskbar icons are system level contols while popup menu is an app specific control inside a target app process.

Comment: Yes I have specified backend="uia". Been there done that. I read all the docs not just the getting started guide. There is no ContextMenu object in the application, even while the menu is being displayed. I've dumped the window identifiers for this app and nothing appears for the context menu.

Comment: Did you try Desktop(backend="uia").window(control_type="Menu") ?

Comment: No menu's found in the desktop object either.

Comment: Hmm... I can see menu in Inspect.exe for any app at my tray icons. They are immediate children of desktop. Probably this app exposes some non-standard menu. Can you provide the screenshot from Inspect.exe?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't install the windows SDK.

Comment: Can you get it from here: https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool ?

Comment: That's outstanding. I've been looking all over the place for a standalone installation. Thanks for that suggestion. I'll get back to you with the results.

Comment: Thanks! But hierarchy view would be more useful. Move mouse to the menu item you wanna click and post the screenshot with a left subtree pane in Inspect.exe (not only properties as you posted now).